# How to generate all combination of multiplication of multiple variables (raised to some powers)

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I want to generate all the possible combinations (commutative) of a few variables but also raised to some fixed powers.

Lets take the following example:
I have three variables `x,y,z`.
The list I want to generate will have all these variables and also their combinations of two of them, three of them, any of them raised to power 2,

```
{x y z, x y,x z,y z, x,y,z, 
 x^2 y^2 z^2, x^2 y^2 z,x^2 y z^2,x y^2 z^2,
 x^2 y z,x y^2 z,x y z^2,
 x^2 y^2,y^2 z^2,x^2 z^2,
 x^2 y,x y^2,x^2 z,x z^2,y^2 z,y z^2,
 x^2,y^2,z^2}
```

Basically all possible combinations of any number of multiplications along with they can take two powers.

**Is there any easier way without incorporating nested `Do` loop?**

Answer (score 5):

```
Inner[#2^# &, Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3], {x, y, z}, Times]
```

> ```
>  {1, z, z^2, y, y z, y z^2, y^2, y^2 z, y^2 z^2, x, x z, x z^2, x y, 
>   x y z, x y z^2, x y^2, x y^2 z, x y^2 z^2, x^2, x^2 z, x^2 z^2, 
>   x^2 y, x^2 y z, x^2 y z^2, x^2 y^2, x^2 y^2 z, x^2 y^2 z^2}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another variation of the [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) approach:

```
Tuples[Unevaluated @ Times[{1, x, x^2}, {1, y, y^2}, {1, z, z^2}]]
```

> {1, z, z^2, y, y z, y z^2, y^2, y^2 z, y^2 z^2, x, x z, x z^2, x y, x y z,
> x y z^2, x y^2, x y^2 z, x y^2 z^2, x^2, x^2 z, x^2 z^2, x^2 y, x^2 y z,
> x^2 y z^2, x^2 y^2, x^2 y^2 z, x^2 y^2 z^2}

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Map[x^#[[1]]y^#[[2]]z^#[[3]]&,Tuples[Range[0,2],3]]
```

which returns

```
{1, z, z^2, y, y*z, y*z^2, y^2, y^2*z, y^2*z^2, x, x*z, x*z^2, x*y, x*y*z,
 x*y*z^2, x*y^2, x*y^2*z, x*y^2*z^2, x^2, x^2*z, x^2*z^2, x^2*y, x^2*y*z,
 x^2*y*z^2, x^2*y^2, x^2*y^2*z, x^2*y^2*z^2}
```

And because there are always multiple different ways of doing anything in Mathematica

```
Map[Times@@Thread[Power[{x,y,z},#]]&,Tuples[Range[0,2],3]]
```

There will be at least half a dozen other different ways of doing this same thing

and

```
Flatten[Table[x^i y^j z^k,{i,0,2},{j,0,2},{k,0,2}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Times@@({x,y,z}^#)&/@{0,1,2}~Tuples~3
```

> {1,z,z^2,y,y z,y z^2,y^2,y^2 z,y^2 z^2,x,x z,x z^2,x y,x y z,x y z^2,x y^2,x y^2 z,x y^2 z^2,x^2,x^2 z,x^2 z^2,x^2 y,x^2 y z,x^2 y z^2,x^2 y^2,x^2 y^2 z,x^2 y^2 z^2}